# Laravel Models connected via Relation Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I am struggeling with Laravel and its Model Interconnection.
I have the following:
4 Tables (`Chapter`, `Headline`, `Question`, `CHQRelation`)
I've created Models for all of them, but now I am wondering how to connect them. At the end, I want to be able to get for a given chapter / headline combination all questions assigned.
My first attempt was to set up a `hasMany` connection from `Chapter` to `CHQRelation`, to receive all relations that have the same chapter. Then I would need a `hasMany` relation from `CHQRelation` to `Headline` to get the all headlines, and then another `hasMany` relation to `Question` to get those. I suppose this is way to complicated, but I can't figure out an easier way and would need a little bit of a push in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tables**:

```
- chapters 
id

- c_h_q_relations
id
chapter_id

- headlines
id
c_h_q_relation_id

- questions
id
c_h_q_relation_id
```

**Models relationships:**

```
class Chapter extends Model
{
    public function cHQRelations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CHQRelation');
    }
}

class CHQRelation extends Model
{
    public function headlines()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Headline');
    }

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
    }

    public function chapter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Chapter');
    }
}

class Headline extends Model
{
    public function cHQRelation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CHQRelation');
    }
}

class Question extends Model
{
    public function cHQRelation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CHQRelation');
    }
}
```

**See also:**

[Laravel best practices](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions)

[Eloquent hasMany relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

[Eloquent belongsTo relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go to https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships for further documentation over relationships with models